# Trouble trying to make a shared library using CMake

Tags: c++, cmake, visual-studio-2017, dynamic-library

So I've decided to try learning and using CMake so that I can make a portable API for Windows, Linux and MacOS.

I've got what I want to call a two part directory tree:

```
/
 PsychoEngine/
              includes/
                       Engine/
                              PsychoEngine.hpp
          src/
              PsychoEngine/
                           Engine/
                                  PsychoEngine.cpp
                                  dir_engine.cmake
                           dir_pe.cmake
              dir_src.cmake
          CMakeLists.txt
 Temp_PE_Game/
          includes/
          src/
              Main/
                   TempPEGameMain.cpp
                   dir_main.cmake
              dir_src.cmake
          CMakeLists.txt
 CMakeLists.txt
```

So Temp_PE_Game is set as an executable so that I can test out everything I write in PsychoEngine. AFAIK, the CMake script for building and running Temp is correct, it runs properly.

However, PsychoEngine, is where I'm struggling. Currently my "root" CMakeLists script for it is:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
project(PsychoEngine)

message("Building PsychoEngine Library.")

set(PROJECT_SRC_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
set(PROJECT_SRC_FILES ${PROJECT_SRC_DIR})

include_directories(${PROJECT_SRC_DIR}/includes
                    ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/exports/)

include(${PROJECT_SRC_DIR}/src/dir_src.cmake)

option(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS "Build Shared Libraries" ON)

set(LIB_TYPE STATIC)
if(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS)
    set(LIB_TYPE SHARED)
endif(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS)

include(GenerateExportHeader)
add_library(PsychoEngine ${LIB_TYPE} ${PROJECT_SRC_FILES})

GENERATE_EXPORT_HEADER(PsychoEngine
                        BASE_NAME PsychoEngine
                        EXPORT_MACRO_NAME PSYCHOENGINE_EXPORT 
                        EXPORT_FILE_NAME ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/exports/PsychoEngineExports.hpp
                        STATIC_DEFINE PsychoEngine_BUILT_AS_STATIC)
```

This too seems to work. However, when I try to import the PsychoEngineExports.hpp in my PsychoEngine.hpp like this:

```
#include "PsychoEngineExports.hpp" /* PEExports.hpp */
#include <iostream>

namespace pe { namespace engine {
    class PSYCHOENGINE_EXPORT PsychoEngine {
    public:
        PsychoEngine();
        int start();
    };
}}
```

Visual Studio's intellisense starts complaining it cannot find PEExports.hpp and class definitions come out in red intermittently.

I thought, oh, might just be that PEExports.hpp hasn't been generated, so I re-ran cmake in my build directory and it still doesn't work.

Here is my Temp_PE_Game CMakeLists.txt:

```
message("Building PE Temp Game.")

set(PROJECT_SRC_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
set(PROJECT_SRC_FILES ${PROJECT_SRC_DIR})

# Include PsychoEngine's headers
include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/PsychoEngine/includes)
include_directories(${PROJECT_SRC_DIR}/includes)

message("PE Game Binary Dir: " ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR})
message("PE Game Executable DIR: " ${EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH})

include(${PROJECT_SRC_DIR}/src/dir_src.cmake)

add_executable(Temp_PE_Game ${PROJECT_SRC_FILES})
```

Any ideas?

Cheers!

Comment: For the case when build directory contains spaces, it is better to wrap paths into quotes: `"${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/exports/PsychoEngineExports.hpp"`. If this doesn't work, show output of command `message(STATUS "Binary dir: ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}")` inserted just before `GENERATE_EXPORT_HEADER` call.

Comment: Didn't work so did the second thing you suggested and this is the output

    Binary Dir: C:/Users/jamie/CMakeBuilds/a339631e-d6a4-0131-bea0-1b077753e93d/build/x86-Debug

Comment: It is not clear from your question - whether the header is actually created (at the place specified by `EXPORT_FILE_NAME` option) or not?

Comment: Note that your executable will now not see the include directory for the export header, as this was set in a different subdirectory. Consider using the modern style of setting include directories through [`target_include_directories`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.10/command/target_include_directories.html) instead, which does not have this issue..